# Inherit from two hierarchical interface?

Tags: c#

I have two interface that one of them has generic type. But when I try to use them I can't.

The first interface is:

```
interface IGene
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Index { get; set; }
}
```

The second is:

```
interface IChromosome<X> where X :IGene
{
    double Fitness { get; }
    X[] Genes { get; set; }
}
```

The class to implement these:

```
class GAMachine<T> where T : IChromosome<X> where X:IGene
{
   //......
}
```

In the last code it gives an error. How can I write this hierarchical order? Any alternative?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `The type or namespace name "X" could not be found`,it says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you did not define X in your class definition in your generic type definitions. I think what you are after though is this.

```
class GAMachine<T> where T : IChromosome<IGene>
{
   //....
}
```

Or this

```
class GAMachine<T, X> where T : IChromosome<X> where X : IGene
{
   //....
}
```

Comment: For your first solution I have a new question. Does it occur a problem when comparing two IGene instance if I use `<IGene>`? My code use comparing and the class user is able to write different comparing methods for the implemented `X` class. So can I compare two same type variable if `<IGene>` is used? Because if I'm not wrong, I know interfaces cannot contain comparing methods, just the class inherited from it can.

Comment: @AliTor - it shouldn't but it depends on your implementation. Ideally you should be overriding Equals and GetHashCode on your concrete types where you want to do a comparison. You can also implement the generic IEquals<T> on your concrete types to execute comparisons. Then the concrete equality implementations should take over when you actually compare instances. But it depends on how you implement your comparisons so I could not say for sure.

Comment: As I understand from you, I should create an additional `IEquals<T>` which contains an `Equals` method. I need user to add a method to check equality too and this way is enough to obligate the user to add an equality method to the inherited class, isn't it?

Comment: @AliTor - If you are asking/expecting the implementer of `IGene` to also provide a suitable equaility methods the easiest way to convey that expectation is to define `IGene` as `interface IGene : IEquatable<IGene>`, see [IEquatable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx).